# How do I make an entry in fstab and make www-data the owner?

Tags: mount, windows, 22.04, nextcloud

I have this Windows File system partition under /dev/sda that I want to automatically mount on every startup. But I just don't know how to add it to fstab because I do not know what its UUID is. I also want www-data to have ownership or access to it since I'm using it as storage for Nextcloud.

What are the steps I must take in order to get this?

Comment: Find its uuid with `sudo lsblk -f`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the UUID of the file system, you can use `sudo blkid`. This will give you a list that looks something like:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="b85a51f1-a0e8-48e3-86e3-4debf67e39c1" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="a2286c86-f278-42c7-b7a4-2c63ce55b6ed"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="B13E-B371" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="24919a71-7b7a-4b64-b4ec-e330ae0a737a"
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="Backup" UUID="f35ffa33-24ec-452c-9bca-6c9307aa1c70" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7688e21d-c1d3-4f02-95ac-5e816e2c1e05"
```

<sup>**Note:** There will also be a number of `squashfs` entries, but those can be ignored.</sup>

From there you can use the UUID in `/etc/fstab` and set Apache as the owner by defining the `uid` (User ID) and `gid` (Group ID) values. As an example, your entry may look like:

```
UUID=f35ffa33-24ec-452c-9bca-6c9307aa1c70    /var/www/files    ntfs-3g   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=33,gid=33,windows_names 0 0
```

<sup>**Note:** Apache *usually* has a User ID and Group ID of `33`. You can verify this with `sudo id -u www-data` and `sudo id -g www-data`.</sup>

Be sure to appropriately modify the example `fstab` line above, as it most certainly will not work as a copy/paste on your system.

Comment: Followed this step for step and it fixed my issue completely! Thank you so much!!

Comment: So after further testing I basically did as you stated

This essentially means that I the owner cannot write data into it anymore. Any folder I try to create gets blocked because owner "www-data" has not permitted me to do so. I believe its to do with the options I set when mounting it in fstab. I do want for www-data to have ownership of just the data folder that happens to exist in /media/joswole/Windows7/JoStorage. But it seems the entirety of Windows 7 has been possessed by www-data and as such I have no control of it anymore unless I remove it. What would I do in this situation?

Comment: In the question you stated “I also want www-data to have ownership”, which is why non-Apache users will need to use `sudo` when writing data. If you want to have this more open, you’ll need to have the volume mounted as a different user. However, be warned that NTFS partitions do not follow Unix-style permission structures, so you will not have the luxury of fine-grained file and directory permissions. If you want to share access to the mount, you’ll want to move the data off NTFS and use something like Ext4 or ZFS.